# SQL Query, return all children in a one-to-many relationship when one child matches

Tags: sql, db2, one-to-many

I'm working on enhancing a query for a DB2 database and I'm having some problems getting acceptable performance due to the number of joins across large tables that need to be performed to get all of the data and I'm hoping that there's a SQL function or technique that can simplify and speed up the process.

To break it down, let's say there are two tables: People and Groups. Groups contain multiple people, and a person can be part of multiple groups. It's a many-to-many, but bear with me. Basically, there's a subquery that will return a set of groups. From that, I can join to People (which requires additional joins across other tables) to get all of the people from those groups. However, I also need to know all of the groups that those people are in, which means joining back to the Groups table again (several more joins) to get a superset of the original subquery. There are additional joins in the query as well to get other pieces of relevant data, and the cost is adding up in a very ugly way. I also need to return information from both tables, so that rules out a number of techniques.

What I'd like to do is be able to start with the People table, join it to Groups, and then compare Groups with the subquery. If the Groups attached to one person has one match in the subquery, it should return ALL Group items associated with that person.

Essentially, let's say that Bob is part of Group A, B, and C. Currently, I start with groups, and let's say that only Group A comes out of the subquery. Then I join A to Bob, but then I have to come back and join Bob to Group again to get B and C. SQL example:

```
SELECT p.*, g2.*
FROM GROUP g
JOIN LINKA link
ON link.GROUPID = g.GROUPID
JOIN LINKB link1
ON link1.LISTID = link.LISTID
JOIN PERSON p
ON link1.PERSONID = p.PERSONID
JOIN LINKB link2
ON link2.PERSONID = p.PERSONID
JOIN LINKA link3
ON link2.LISTID = link3.LISTID
JOIN GROUP g2
ON link3.GROUPID = g2.GROUPID
WHERE
g.GROUPID IN (subquery)
```

Yes, the linking tables aren't ideal, but they're basically normalized tables containing additional information that is not relevant to the query I'm running. We have to start with a filtered Group set, join to People, then come back to get all of the Groups that the People are associated to.

What I'd like to do is start with People, join to Group, and if ANY Group that Bob is in returns from the subquery, ALL should be returned, so if we have Bob joined to A, B, and C, and A is in the subquery, it will return three rows of Bob to A, B, and C as there was at least one match. In this way, it could be treated as a one-to-many relationship if we're only concerned with the Groups for each Person and not the other way around. SQL example:

```
SELECT p.*, g.*
FROM PEOPLE p
JOIN LINKB link
ON link.PERSONID = p.PERSONID
JOIN LINKA link1
ON link.LISTID = link1.LISTID
JOIN GROUP g
ON link1.GROUPID = g.GROUPID
WHERE
--SQL function, expression, or other method to return 
--all groups for any person who is part of any group contained in the subquery
```

The number of joins in the first query make it largely unusable as these are some pretty big tables. The second would be far more ideal if this sort of thing is possible.

Comment: How is this question different from the [question you asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076916/sql-query-joining-a-many-to-many-relationship-filtering-joining-selectively/17077678#17077678)?  If you need to ask the question a different way, or explain yourself better, then edit the original question.  For example, explain what the difference is between LINKA and LINKB. Or are they really the same table?

Answer (score 0):

From the question, I think you are querying hierarchical data. DB2 provides facility to deal with such data. There are two clauses Start with and Connect by in DB2 which will be useful. They are explained [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-db2connectby/).

Comment: Urg, I should probably specify that I'm using DB2 for LUW, which doesn't appear to include CONNECT BY. In any case, it's close, but that appears to be used for recursive queries within the same table, which isn't quite what I'm trying to do. There's really only one direct relationship I'm trying to use. I just need to return the full set of children associated with a parent in another table when one child matches any elements in a given set.

Comment: @Darshan DB2 for i handles hierarchical queries better than the other platforms.  We're lucky in that regard at least.  But it is also more than is needed for this. For example, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076916/sql-query-joining-a-many-to-many-relationship-filtering-joining-selectively/17077678#17077678).